# How to block a browser by full name including compatible?

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer

I have many requests get\post from different ip with the browser Mozilla 5.0 compatible MSIE 9.0 on the main page of website. I don't want to block Mozilla fully, I need to block only this occurance. Can I do it?

In my apache logs it looks like:

**172.68.25.54 - - [19/Sep/2018:18:00:32 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 11059 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0)"**

If I use this rule:

```
BrowserMatchNoCase "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0)" bad_br
Deny from env=bad_br
```

It doesn't work, I think it's just because of un-quoted string or something else...

Comment: it was easier just to block in php for me/

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of BrowserMatchNoCase is not an ordinary string but a **regex** (regular expression). Bracket symbols are the special symbols in regex and need to be escaped with backslash if you want to match them in a string:

`BrowserMatchNoCase "Mozilla/5.0 \(compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0\)" bad_br`